# Assuming answer to be true

Tags: single-word-requests

This is more of a mathematical context (as opposed to literary context). We assume the statement we have to prove to be true (assumption) and on the basis of that we draw deductions from the statement and draw some conditions for the statement to be true and in the end, come to the conclusion that since these conditions (given in question) are imperative for satisfying the answer so the statement is true. E.g.:

> Example 18 Show that if f : A → B and g : B → C are one-one, then gof : A → C is also one-one.
>   Solution:
>   **Suppose** gof(x1) = gof(x2).
>   g(f(x1)) =g(f(x2)).
>   f(x1) = f(x2), as g is one-one.
>   x1 =x2, as f is one-one.
>   **Hence**  gof (x1)= gof (x2).

What is this "method" called?

Comment: 'Incorrect' seems the best match to me... This is a textbook logical fallacy 'beg the question' https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/begging-the-question

Comment: OK after the edit it looks like maybe you're looking for `postulate`

Comment: It's called *circular reasoning*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not at all...that is something else...you don't know maths.

Comment: @Argot Your terminology and symbology is different from what I learned (almost two decades ago). Are you looking for [transitive relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)? Or are you looking for the word [isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism)? Or are you looking for [formal theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_%28mathematical_logic%29)?

Comment: As an aside, where did you learn to put a whitespace before a question mark but none before an opening parenthesis or after a period? Nobody else does that, so please do not do that, either. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt of course , I didn't learn it anywhere (I guess that is satire)..I just don't happen to take care of such intricacies and I obviously know the right way.But thanks for pointing out,I am little messed up on presentation issues.

Comment: I can simplify your proof for you:  
**1.** Suppose gof(x1) = gof(x2). **2.** Hence gof(x1) = gof(x2). **3.** This is the Law of Identity.

Comment: Also, it is generally accepted in the mathematical community that if you are careless with something as simple as punctuation, then you will be taken less seriously. Writing proofs for yourself is one thing.  Writing proofs for others is communication. See [Some Remarks on Writing Mathematical Proofs](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Writing/writing-proofs.pdf) and [Guidelines for Writing Mathematical Proofs](http://community.plu.edu/~sklarjk/499/proofguidelines.pdf) in which using proper grammar and punctuation is considered important.

Comment: i like your link very much but you are incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what word you are looking for but here are a bunch of terms relevant to the context.

Firstly, your example would constitute a "proof":

> [proof](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proof) — 3. *maths*, *logic* direct induction. See also induction a sequence of steps or statements that establishes the truth of a proposition.

The listed assumptions at the beginning of a proof would be "postulates", "assumptions" or "premises":

> [postulates](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/postulates?s=t) — 6. Mathematics, Logic.  a proposition that requires no proof, being self-evident, or that is for a specific purpose assumed true, and that is used in the proof of other propositions; axiom.
>
> [assumption](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Assumption?s=t) — something taken for granted; a supposition: a correct assumption. Synonyms: presupposition; hypothesis, conjecture, guess, postulate, theory.
>
> [premise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/premise?s=t) — 1. Also, premiss. *Logic*. a proposition supporting or helping to support a conclusion.

You can already see lots of other synonyms and similar terms in the definitions quoted.

---

Your particular proof, by the way, seems suspect for a two reasons:

> 1. Suppose gof(x1) = gof(x2)
> 2. g(f(x1)) = g(f(x2)).
> 3. f(x1) = f(x2), as g is one-one.
> 4. x1 = x2, as f is one-one.
> 5. Hence gof(x1) = gof(x2).

Firstly, (1) does not include the relevant note that g(x) and f(x) are one-one *or* the define the step used in (3) and (4). Secondly, it doesn't prove gof(x1) = gof(x2) because that's what you started with. You could have just said:

> 1. Suppose gof(x1) = gof(x2)
> 2. Hence gof(x1) = gof(x2).

What you *probably* meant to use for your last step is something like:

> Hence gof is one-one since x1 = x2 when gof(x1) = gof(x2)

Comment: I think you’re right that the last line wasn’t quite right.  Surely it should be: “Hence g.f is an isomorphism”.

Answer (score 2):

The method of argumentation you’re asking about isn’t logically valid.  But it’s also not what’s going on in the proof in question.

---

*Regarding the actual proof*

The individual statements on separate lines are linked by an implicit series of *if and only if*’s:

> g ∘ f(x) = g ∘ f(y)
>
> ⇔ g(f(x)) = g(f(y))
>
> ⇔ f(x) = f(y) — given that g an isomorphism
>
> ⇔ x = y — given that f is an isomorphism

But there’s no “direction” to this proof.  It’s a series of logical equivalences and you could just as well write it backwards:

> x = y
>
> ⇔ f(x) = f(y) — given that f is an isomorphism
>
> ⇔ g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) — given that g an isomorphism
>
> ⇔ g ∘ f(x) = g ∘ f(y)

---

*Regarding the name of the style of proof*

After a brief foray into math.stackexchange.com, it turns out that the style of proof above is called, simply, a *direct proof*.  Quoting wikipedia:

> In mathematics and logic, a *direct proof* is a way of showing the truth
> or falsehood of a given statement by a straightforward combination of
> established facts, usually existing lemmas and theorems, without
> making any further assumptions. ... Logical deduction is employed to
> reason from assumptions to conclusion. The type of logic employed is
> almost invariably first-order logic, employing the quantifiers for all
> and there exists.

---

*Regarding the method of argumentation you’re proposing*

In basic logic, if P is a proposition and T, a true statement, then (P → T) is true regardless of whether P is true or false.  So, deducing a truth from a statement P tells you nothing about the truth value of P: it could be either true or false.  After all, anything is deducible from a contradiction, but a contradiction isn’t true.

A complementary method of argumentation that is logically valid is “proof by contradiction”.  To prove that P is true, you assume that P is false and deduce that some other statement, Q, is false (or true), when, in fact, Q is independently known to be true (or false).  This works because valid deductions from true premises cannot yield falsehoods—which is the opposite, sort of, of what the previous paragraph says: valid deductions from false premises can yield truths.

A good deal of mathematical energy is sometimes expended examining what happens if contentious hypotheses are assumed to be true (or false).  Before (and doubtless after) the proof of the independence of the Axiom of Choice, the axiom was explored in precisely this way (leading to some very curious results, such as the Banach-Tarski decomposition).  Similarly, there was (I’m informed) a general expectation that Fermat’s last theorem would be proved true, because supposition of its truth led to a batch of highly plausible and consistent results—but, crucially, these results were not taken as proof of the theorem itself.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer but I don't think it actually answers the English part of the question. :)

Comment: True!  That's now fixed

Comment: sorry , i really wanted to accept your answer -- your answer is a good reading but i am not able to grasp much of it--to be honest--if i am able to sometime later --then i will accept your answer    P.S :thats a logical(as opposed to analytical or mathemaical)answer---and which are invariably the most difficult to grasp in the beginning but once you get the hang of it,its hard to let go......